# How to write multiple line caption with figure

Tags: floats, captions

How to split a long figure caption to multiple line? Using `\\` doesn't work.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{x.jpg}
\caption{line 1...
    line 2...
    line 3...} 
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Explicit line breaks can be given with `\newline`.  For more sophisticated caption styling use the [`caption` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption).

Comment: Also don't use `[H]` (It's almost always a bad idea)

Comment: In `beamer` `\newline` works, but the caption is not centered, any suggestions?

Answer (score 25):

Load the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package; now you can use the standard line change command `\\`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{x}
\caption{line 1 \\line 2 \\ line 3 } 
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: using "\usepackage{caption}" with "\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}" cause an incompatibility formation, putting all caption on left side. Do you any additional suggest?